# Embedding $X \ni x \mapsto \delta_x \in P_2(X)$ is totally convex

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, optimal-transport

I am looking for a reference to a proof of the following result:

> Let $X$ be a compact, connected, smooth Riemannian manifold. Then, the embedding
> $$X \ni x \mapsto \delta_x \in P_2(X) $$
> has totally convex image.

In the above, $P_2(X)$ denotes the $2$-Wasserstein space on $X$, and $\delta_x$ is the Dirac measure at $x$.

I saw this result in Lott and Villani's paper on synthetic Ricci curvature bounds. In Villani's books on optimal transport, I was able to find a proof that the above map is an isometric embedding, but not that it has totally convex image.

Thank you in advance for the reference.

Comment: What do you mean by a "totally convex" subset of $P_2(X)$. Just that it contains all minimizing geodesics with endpoints inside this set? in metric geometry, geodesic usually means a length minimizing curve, while this is not the case in Riemannian geometry.

Comment: Where exactly did you find the claim? Unless I am misunderstanding something (which is highly probable), or some definitions are different, it seems false to me. Take the sphere, and consider the north pole $N$ and the south pole $S$. Then any constant-speed meridian is a geodesic between $\delta_N$ and $\delta_S$. In particular, you can consider any superposition of such paths, which are in general not deltas. For example: $\mu_t$ equal to the renormalized length measure on a parallel, with the parallels swiping the sphere from $N$ to $S$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is false, as @Del pointed out, and the same example can be found here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.2883 (the paragraph after Proposition 3.7; be careful with the terminology in this paper and what I say in the next paragraph!).

Lott's and Villani's paper mentions that the map is **totally geodesic**, which, in the context of, for instance, proving that the $2$-Wasserstein space has non-negative curvature iff $X$ does, I think means that geodesics in $X$ are mapped to geodesics in $P_2(X)$.